# How to programmatically create an exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to create programmatically exposed filters in Drupal 7?

I searched a lot but I found only topics related remove or alter exposed filters already available in a view.

By instance my view doesn't provide any exposed filter. 
I must create it through the code in my module.
I have a view but I can't change it via Views administration interface.
I must achieve the result by implementing [hook_views_pre_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7.x-3.x) and [add_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/views_db_object%3A%3Aadd_item/7.x-3.x).

Unfortunately add_item is not very well documented or, at least, not the part concerning the $options array structure.

Given 'field_status' a "select list" with 3 items defined in the field configuration, and the following piece of code:

```
 function hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
   $field = field_info_field('field_status');
   if (!empty($field)) {
    $filter = array(
     'identifier' => 'field_status',
     'exposed' => TRUE,
     'is_grouped' => FALSE,
     'table' => 'field_data_field_status',
     'type' => 'list_text',
     'expose' => array(
       'operator_id' => 'field_status_value',
       'label' => 'Status',
     )
   );
   $view->add_item($view->current_display, 'filter', 'field_data_field_status', 'field_status_value', $filter);
   $view->display_handler->set_option('css_class', 'view-status');
}
```

what should be the structure of the array $options (in my case $filter)?

As a result of this I can see the submit button 'Apply' and the label "Status" in an empty widget 'div'.

Here is the code edited following suggestions in comments:

```
function my_module_views_default_views_alter(&$views) {
  if (array_key_exists('my_view_name', $views)) {

    $options = array (
      0 => 'Blocked',
      1 => 'Active',
    );

    $display = $views['my_view_name']->display['my_view_page'];

    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['id'] = 'field_status';
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['table'] = 'field_data_field_status';
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['field'] = 'field_status';
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_status_value';
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['label'] = 'Status';
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_status_value';
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_status';
    $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['value'] = $options;

    $views['my_view_name']->display['my_view_page'] = $display;
  }
}
```

--- ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION ---

Since this problem seems to be hard to fix (@ least for my specific case) I have used a workaround to achieve the goal.
The solution consists basically on a Views Block Clone with Exposed Filters which overrides the Views Block (without exposed filters) according to specific cases (Is User LoggedIn, Content Type, Contextual Filters ecc..).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try with hook_views_default_views_alter function. This function should be defined in MODULE_NAME/views/MODULE_NAME.views.inc file. And don't forget to include this file on .info file as `files[] = views/MODULE_NAME.views.inc.`

```
 function MODULE_NAME_views_default_views_alter(&$views) {
        if (array_key_exists('MY_VIEW_NAME', $views)) {
          $options = array(
          0 => 'Blocked',
          1 => 'Active',
          ); 
          $display = $views['MY_VIEW_NAME']->display['MY_VIEW_PAGE'];
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['id'] = 'field_status';
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['table'] = 'field_data_field_status';
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['field'] = 'field_status';
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['value'] = $options;
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['exposed'] = TRUE;
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_status_value';
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['label'] = 'Status';
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_status_value';
          $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_status';
          $views['MY_VIEW_NAME']->display['MY_VIEW_PAGE'] = $display;
          }
    }
```

Comment: Great, thanks for precious information. I will make a test and will return to you with a feedback for this solution.

Comment: Welcome. Please try and confirm if it got worked..

Comment: Hi, the solution looks good in terms of cleanliness. Unfortuantely I got the same result with label and submit 'Apply' but no select list field. I also got the Notice: Undefined index: field_tags in views_handler_filter->accept_exposed_input(). Moreover, as far as I understood, this hook must be implemented streight in .module file otherwise it doesn't work. Any idea about that? Thank you anyway for your help!! I really appreciate

Comment: Can u please include below code in to the above statement. I will edit my answer.                                                                                   $options = array(
          0 => 'Blocked',
          1 => 'Active',
        );                                                              $display->display_options['filters']['field_status']['value'] = $options;

Comment: Hi, I have added the snippet of code on my comment above.

Comment: The problem is that I'm still getting the same result... I don't know if it depends by Organic Groups module. I will make a test on a simple Drupal instance just to have a more clear picture and will return to you with a feedback of course! :) Thanks!!